# Update table from another table using dynamic column references in MySql 5.7

Tags: mysql, database, stored-procedures, sql-update, compare

I have two tables NEW_TBL and CURRENT_TBL.

The values in CURRENT_TBL need to be updated so they are equal to NEW_TBL. Both tables have a PK named tableId, but the columns in NEW_TBL will not always match CURRENT_TBL. I already have what I need make the schema's the same, but I need a method for updating CURRENT_TBL's values based on a dynamic column reference.

Here's a contrived example of how I would accomplish this in javascript.

Starting tables:

```
currentTable = [
  ['tableId','col2','col3','col4'],
  ['1','purple','blue','pink'],
  ['2','purple','red','orange'],
  ['3','green','yellow','purple']
];


newTable = [
  ['tableId','col2','col3','col4'],
  ['1','','blue','pink'],
  ['2','magenta','blue','pink'],
  ['4','grey','black','white']
];
```

Function:

```
function updateCurrentTable() {
  var currentHeader = currentTable[0];
  var newHeader = newTable[0];
  var currentValues = currentTable.slice(1);
  var newValues = newTable.slice(1);

  var newIdList = newValues.map(function(val){ // Get list of newTable ids
    return val[0];
  })

  var currentIdList = currentValues.map(function(val){ // Get list of newTable ids
    return val[0];
  })

  for (var newColumn = 0; newColumn<newHeader.length; newColumn++) { // Loop through new table columns
    var columnName = newHeader[newColumn];
    var newIdColumn = newHeader.indexOf('tableId');
    var currentColumnIndex = currentHeader.indexOf(columnName);
    var currentIdIndex = currentHeader.indexOf('tableId');

    if (columnName !== 'tableId') { // The tableId column is skipped because the id will never be altered

      for (var newRow = 0; newRow<newValues.length; newRow++) { // Loop through new table rows
        var newId = newValues[newRow][newIdColumn];
        var newValue = newValues[newRow][newColumn];

        if (currentIdList.indexOf(newId) < 0) { // If tableId exists in newTable but not in currentTable, add the row to currentTable
          currentValues.push(newValues[newRow]);
          currentIdList.push(newId); // Update the id list
        }

        for (var curRow =0; curRow < currentValues.length; curRow++) { // Loop through current table rows
          var currentId = currentValues[curRow][currentIdIndex];

          if (currentColumnIndex !== currentIdIndex) { // The tableId column is skipped because the id will never be altered

            if (newIdList.indexOf(currentId) < 0) { // If tableId exists in currentTable but not newTable, remove the row from currentTable
              currentValues.splice(curRow,1);
            } else if (newId === currentId) { // If the tableIds match, update the value in the current column
              currentValues[curRow][currentColumnIndex] = newValue; 
            } 
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  Logger.log(currentValues)
}
```

Result:

```
currentTable = [
  ['tableId','col2','col3','col4'],
  ['1','','blue','pink'],
  ['2','magenta','blue','pink'],
  ['4','grey','black','white']
];
```

Is there a way to accomplish the above in SQL?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with a solution that dynamically creates the portion of the SQL statement comparing columns (i.e. "currentTable.cost = newTable.cost") then runs an UPDATE JOIN with the dynamic list of columns.

```
DELIMITER //
 CREATE PROCEDURE matchCurrentToNew()
 COMMENT 'Update currentTable to match newTable'
 BEGIN

    DECLARE num_rows INT;
    DECLARE col_name TINYTEXT;
    DECLARE concatStatement TINYTEXT;
    DECLARE concatFields TINYTEXT;
    DECLARE done TINYINT DEFAULT FALSE; 

    DECLARE col_names 
      CURSOR FOR
        SELECT column_name
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
        WHERE table_name = 'TASKS'
        ORDER BY ordinal_position;

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    SET concatStatement = "";
    OPEN col_names;

    SELECT FOUND_ROWS() into num_rows;

    the_loop: LOOP

        FETCH NEXT FROM col_names    
        INTO col_name; 

        IF done THEN
          CLOSE col_names;
          LEAVE the_loop;
        END IF;

        IF col_name <> "UniqueId" AND col_name <> "ProjectId" THEN
            SET concatFields = CONCAT_WS("=",
                                     CONCAT_WS(".","currentTable",col_name),
                                     CONCAT_WS(".","newTable",col_name)
                                    );

            SET concatStatement = CONCAT(concatStatement,",",concatFields);         
        END IF;

    END LOOP the_loop;

    #     Remove comma at the beginning of the concatStatement string

    SET concatStatement = TRIM(LEADING "," FROM concatStatement);

    SET @sqlText = CONCAT(
      'UPDATE currentTable  
      JOIN newTable
      ON currentTable .UniqueId = newTable.UniqueId 
      AND currentTable .ProjectId = newTable.ProjectId
      SET ', concatStatement
    );

    PREPARE stmt FROM @sqlText;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;

 END //
 DELIMITER ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand that you want to match the tables on column `tableId`, and update `colHeader` in `current_tbl` with the corresponding value from `new_tbl`.

For this, you can take advantage of the MySQL `update ... join ... set` syntax:

```
update current_tbl c
inner join new_tbl n on c.tableId   = n.tableId
set c.colHeader = n.colHeader
```

Comment: Thank you, GMB. I have come across this solutions many times, but it still requires that I manually update the column headers. How do I make the column reference dynamic? I want to update the table value if the row and column match in both tables match.

Comment: I believe my question may not have been clear. I have edited and added an example for clarity.